# Unit testing with FakeAsync in Dart

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, dart

I'm kind of new to unit testing, and I am writing a unit test which uses the [quiver package](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) for faking async execution. The function I am using looks something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:quiver/testing/async.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart' as tester;

testStream<MyType>(
  String message, {
  Iterable expecting,
  Future<void> Function(BehaviorSubject) action,
  Duration waitTime,
  int skip = 1,
}) {
  tester.test(message, () {
    final _stream = BehaviorSubject<MyType>();
    FakeAsync().run((async) async {
      final List<MyType> _results = <MyType>[];
      final _subscription = _stream.skip(skip).listen(_results.add);
      await action?.call(_stream);

      if (waitTime != null) async.elapse(waitTime);

      _subscription.cancel();
      if (expecting != null) {
        tester.expect(_results, expecting);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

It works well on most tests I wrote, but I am having problems with a specific example due to the lack of knowledge. In the particular case I pass the action which adds a delayed future to the stream similarly like this:

```dart
testStream<int>(
  'Just a basic message',
  expecting: [1],
  action: (stream) async =>
       Future.delayed(Duration(days: 99), () => stream.add(1)),
  waitTime: Duration(seconds: 1),
);
```

If I understood it right, this test should fail, however when I run it, it passes. **What am I doing wrong here**?

Then, what should I do to make it execute the action first and then elapse the timer after the action has been called without waiting for it?

Comment: Can you provide the exact code of your test?  If `action?.call(_stream)` returns that delayed `Future`, the `await` will just wait for it to complete before you even get to `async.elapse`.

Comment: @jamesdlin That was just a simple example, but I updated the question now. Any idea on what should I change to make it working?  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: "make it working"?  I don't understand.  Your test is already passing.  Do you want it to timeout?  Anyway, currently your test passes because of what I previously stated: you `await action?.call(_stream);` waits for the `Future.delayed(...)` that is returned by the supplied `action`.  If don't want to wait, then remove the `await`.

Comment: @jamesdlin hmm, that's weird. When I run it, it still fails. Tried removing the await, but no avail. Then, looks like I'll have to look more into where the error may be coming from. Thank you kind sir!